# Uncompressed size of a webpage using chunked transfer encoding and gzip compression

Tags: python, http, gzip, transfer-encoding

I'm writing an application that calculates the savings we got after using gzip on a web page. When the user inputs the URL of the web page that used gzip, the application should spit out the savings in size due to gzip.

How should I approach this problem?

This is what I am getting as header for a GET request on the page:

```
{
    'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 
    'Server': 'nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2016 09:49:58 GMT',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
}
```

I am retrieving the page with `requests`:

```
r  = requests.get(url, headers)
data = r.text
print "Webpage size : " , len(data)/1024
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already downloaded the URL (using a `requests` `GET` request without the `stream` option, you already have both sizes available as the whole response is downloaded and decompressed, and the original length is available in the headers:

```
from __future__ import division

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
compressed_length = int(r.headers['content-length'])
decompressed_length = len(r.content)

ratio = compressed_length / decompressed_length
```

You *could* compare a `Accept-Encoding: identity` HEAD request content-length header with one with setting `Accept-Encoding: gzip` instead:

```
no_gzip = {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}
no_gzip.update(headers)
uncompressed_length = int(requests.get(url, headers=no_gzip).headers['content-length'])
force_gzip = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
force_gzip.update(headers)
compressed_length = int(requests.get(url, headers=force_gzip).headers['content-length'])
```

However, this may not work for all servers, as dynamically-generated content servers routinely futz the Content-Length header in such cases to avoid having to render the content first.

If you are requesting a [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) resource, there won't *be* a content-length header, in which case a HEAD request may or may not provide you with the correct information either.

In that case you'd *have* to stream the whole response and extract the decompressed size from the end of the stream (the GZIP format includes this as a little-endian 4-byte unsigned int at the very end). Use the [`stream()` method](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.stream) on the raw urllib3 response object:

```
import requests
from collections import deque

if hasattr(int, 'from_bytes'):
    # Python 3.2 and up
    _extract_size = lambda q: int.from_bytes(bytes(q), 'little')
else:
    import struct
    _le_int = struct.Struct('<I').unpack
    _extract_size = lambda q: _le_int(b''.join(q))[0]

def get_content_lengths(url, headers=None, chunk_size=2048):
    """Return the compressed and uncompressed lengths for a given URL

    Works for all resources accessible by GET, regardless of transfer-encoding
    and discrepancies between HEAD and GET responses. This does have
    to download the full request (streamed) to determine sizes.

    """
    only_gzip = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
    only_gzip.update(headers or {})
    # Set `stream=True` to ensure we can access the original stream:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=only_gzip, stream=True)
    r.raise_for_status()
    if r.headers.get('Content-Encoding') != 'gzip':
        raise ValueError('Response not gzip-compressed')
    # we only need the very last 4 bytes of the data stream
    last_data = deque(maxlen=4)
    compressed_length = 0
    # stream directly from the urllib3 response so we can ensure the
    # data is not decompressed as we iterate
    for chunk in r.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=False):
        compressed_length += len(chunk)
        last_data.extend(chunk)
    if compressed_length < 4:
        raise ValueError('Not enough data loaded to determine uncompressed size')
    return compressed_length, _extract_size(last_data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> compressed_length, decompressed_length = get_content_lengths('http://httpbin.org/gzip')
>>> compressed_length
179
>>> decompressed_length
226
>>> compressed_length / decompressed_length
0.7920353982300885
```

Comment: i am getting headers without content-length, what can we do on such cases?

Comment: @BinuMathew: you mean you have [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked` responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)? Please do be *specific* in your questions, giving an example of what kind of content you are dealing with can help us help you much better. Do edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @BinuMathew: There is a `Content-Length` header right there.

Comment: @Martijin : as i am not getting content-length using get, i was using request.head method

Answer (score 1):

Sending the HEAD request with and without accepting gzip compression and comparing Content-Length header between results.

'accept-encoding' header helps you to request with gzip compression:

```
'accept-encoding': 'gzip'
```

In this case, request without gzip encoding.

```
'accept-encoding': ''
```

Sending the HEAD request will be easily handled by [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library:

```
import requests
r = requests.head("http://stackoverflow.com/", headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})
print(r.headers['content-length'])
```

41450

```
r = requests.head("http://stackoverflow.com/", headers={'Accept-Encoding': ''})
print(r.headers['content-length'])
```

250243

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why you need to request twice with and without gzip compression.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is a parser, it's not helpful for getting data size.

Comment: Oh I meant, using "the content length is not going to change between a HEAD and a GET" and "request without gzip compression", we can easily getting the uncompressed data size. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I fear that not all HTTP servers will actually correctly differentiate between HEAD requests with and without an `Accept` with gzip switched on.

Comment: For example, websites that dynamically generate content can end up sending you a *supposed* content-length, without compression applied, because the actual content is not generated for a HEAD request.